# PowerShell To update Drivers of a computer

Tags: powershell, driver

I am trying to build a powershell script with logic to identify a currently installed driver version.

if it is the same (as the one i am trying to install or newer) skip the install.

If it is lower than the version i am trying to install execute a setup.exe with silent argument.

```
$NetworkName = Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, driverversion | where {$_.devicename -eq 'Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM'}

If ($_.Driverversion -ge '12.17.8.9') { 

Write-Output "Version is Current"

return 0

} Else {

start-process -filepath "\\servername\share\share\Dell\Drivers\Dell 3630\Network Card\setup.exe" -argumentlist '/s' -Wait -NoNewWindow

}
```

this works and installs the newest driver, but it doesn't skip computers that already have the newest version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, i did a lot of googling but since i am still learning, i am pretty sure its just a rookie overlook.

I posted my question on technet as well.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/249a930f-0989-4734-bd8b-f30bbbc838ca/powershell-to-update-drivers-of-a-computer?forum=winserverpowershell#445d46ff-aa29-4960-9258-e7504a643aa6

Comment: Could you please next time you crosspost the same question in different forums at least place links to the other crossposts to your questions. That would avoid getting the same advices twice and would help us helping you. Thanks   [MS Scripting Guys forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aae95bbf-3893-4bc9-8d3a-68bef1f8c111/need-help-with-renaming-files-with-square-brackets-in-file-names?forum=ITCG#31783386-7974-4c05-9790-da63df36f622)

Comment: Hello Olaf, i appreciate your help in the other forum. I am new to asking for help on forums and wasn't ware you awesome people help everywhere. I will edit my post and provide the link to the other forum that you helped me with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script selects the drivers, but then does nothing with the result..

I think this should do it:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver | 
    Where-Object {$_.devicename -eq 'Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ([Version]$_.Driverversion -ge [Version]'12.17.8.9') {  
            Write-Output "Version is Current"
            # return from a function ?
            # return 0
            # exit script with exitcode?
            # exit 0
        } 
        else {
            Start-Process -FilePath "\\servername\share\share\Dell\Drivers\Dell 3630\Network Card\setup.exe" -ArgumentList '/s' -Wait -NoNewWindow
        }
    }
```

I have also altered the check on the driver version by casting the strings to `System.Version` objects. That way the comparison will be correct as opposed to comparing strings.

Comment: Appreciate the help Theo, Olaf and you helped me get the info i needed.